# we can also initialize any employee type class on a constructor then why should we implement onit() in angular 2

Tags: angular, constructor

In angular why should we initialize a a property in onit() if we can do it constructor itself. if we getting it from Services classes

Answer (score 0):

`NgOnInit()` is called *after* `constructor()`. While it can be relevant in some cases to just do everything inside of a constructor, `NgOnInit()` runs as a life-cycle hook, i.e. when the component is finished creating the component. In fact, it actually runs after a `NgOnChanges()`. So understanding this break down in component rendering actually makes it easier to break down a component and probably make it more testable.

Remember Angular is a framework; you don't have to follow it's practices, but it is designed to function optimally in those constraints.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence